# How can i add an information message to the checkout

Tags: magento2, messages, checkout-page

I have a demo site using the default luma theme and I want to add a simple information message to the checkout above the delivery options.

Where about in the template can I edit this, I'm not bothered about best practise I just want to hack it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add text before shipping method from this file:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

Override this core file to your custom theme at

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html

Add your text before `<li id="opc-shipping_method">` or where you want to show.

After chnages run following commands to deploy static files

> php bin/magento static:content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: for a bonus point what class do i add so they box is blue? i've tried class="message-notice notice message"

Comment: @Tristanisginger you can use __`class="success message"`__ for green color. Use __`class="error message"`__ for red color. Use __`class="notice message"`__ for notice color